# How to create query or store procedure on MS SQL Server to expand column from row

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

Need help from you all in writing up this query.

```
Field 1  
========
Hello
Man
Lady
```

I need to result :

```
F1             F2             F3
=================================
Hello          Null           Null
Man            Null           Null
Lady           Null           Null
Hello          Man            Null
Hello          Lady           Null
Man            Lady           Null
Hello          Man            Lady
==================================
```

Comment: I can solve this problem by programming but I don't want to run on client side.

Comment: What if there is a 4th value, should there be four columns and 15 rows?

Comment: Also is there another column in the table that can predictably determine that "hello" is "first"?

Comment: In row 6, does it matter for Man/Lady or Lady/Man?

Comment: Don't worry sorting. Because I give an example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With no other column to ensure Man comes before Lady, this works. So some permutations here are reversed to your output

Add another value and it gets complicated though

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (SomeCol varchar(30));

INSERT @t VALUES ('Hello'), ('Man'), ('Lady');

SELECT *
FROM
    (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        t1.SomeCol AS F1,
        CASE WHEN t2.SomeCol = t1.SomeCol THEN NULL ELSE t2.SomeCol END AS F2,
        CASE WHEN t2.SomeCol = t1.SomeCol OR t3.SomeCol = t1.SomeCol OR t3.SomeCol = t2.SomeCol THEN NULL ELSE t3.SomeCol END AS F3
        --,
        --CASE WHEN NULLIF(t2.SomeCol, t1.SomeCol) IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE NULLIF(NULLIF(t3.SomeCol, t2.SomeCol), NULLIF(t3.SomeCol, t1.SomeCol)) END AS F3
    FROM
        @t t1
        JOIN
        @t t2 ON t1.SomeCol <= t2.SomeCol
        JOIN
        @t t3 ON t2.SomeCol <= t3.SomeCol
    ) X
ORDER BY
    F3, F2, F1;
```

With some other ordering column

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (ID int IDENTITY(1,1), SomeCol varchar(30));

INSERT @t VALUES ('Hello'), ('Man'), ('Lady');

SELECT *
FROM 
    (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        t1.SomeCol AS F1,
        CASE WHEN t2.SomeCol = t1.SomeCol THEN NULL ELSE t2.SomeCol END AS F2,
        CASE WHEN t2.SomeCol = t1.SomeCol OR t3.SomeCol = t1.SomeCol OR t3.SomeCol = t2.SomeCol THEN NULL ELSE t3.SomeCol END AS F3
    FROM
        @t t1
        JOIN
        @t t2 ON t1.ID <= t2.ID
        JOIN
        @t t3 ON t2.ID <= t3.ID
    ) X
ORDER BY
    F3, F2, F1;
```

Comment: +1 slightly less complex (but still not able to order exactly as in the OP): http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e8241/1

Comment: +1 as it's a nice solution, however, not too flexible - does what the asker wants, though :)

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a function which gives back all combinations of items in a list. You need to work a bit on this function in order to get the results "as dataset" (so it won't return the combinations only -as list items- but what you want to see).

```
USE [MYDB_NAME_HERE]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ItemCombinations]    (
   @strSep char(1) = ';',       --REQUIRED, the character to split the @List string on
   @myItemList varchar(max),    --REQUIRED, list of items which should be combined
   @minUse int,         --combine at least this number of items from the list
   @maxUse int          --combine at most this number of items from the list
                                            )
RETURNS @combos TABLE (myCols varchar(max))
AS
BEGIN
    IF (@myItemList = '')
        RETURN
    DECLARE @tmpRetVal TABLE    (
                                    unID tinyint IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED,
                                    cols varchar(500),
                                    bitV AS CONVERT (integer, POWER(2, unID - 1)) PERSISTED UNIQUE CLUSTERED
                                )
    DECLARE @tmpRes TABLE       (
                                    colcount int NULL,
                                    cols varchar(max)
                                )

    INSERT INTO @tmpRetVal (cols)
        SELECT * FROM dbo.StrSplit (';',@myItemList) AS cols

    DECLARE @max integer = POWER (2, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @tmpRetVal AS tRET)) - 1;

    INSERT INTO @tmpRes (cols)
        SELECT combination = STUFF ((   SELECT @strSep + tRET.cols 
                                        FROM @tmpRetVal AS tRET
                                        WHERE NUM.Number & tRET.bitV = tRET.bitV
                                        ORDER BY tRET.bitV
                                        FOR XML PATH (''),
                                        TYPE).value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(8000)'), 1, 1, '')
        FROM [dbo].[Numbers] AS NUM
        WHERE NUM.Number BETWEEN 1 AND @max;

    UPDATE @tmpRes SET colcount = (LEN(cols) - LEN(REPLACE(cols, @strSep, '')) + 1)

    DELETE FROM @tmpRes WHERE (colcount  @maxUse)

    INSERT INTO @combos (myCols)
        SELECT cols FROM @tmpRes
    RETURN
END
```

Test run from immediate with (e.g.) this guy here:

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[ItemCombinations] (';','Lady;Man;Hello',1,3)
GO
```

will give this result set:
`Lady

Man

Lady;Man

Foo

Lady;Foo

Man;Foo

Lady;Man;Foo`
Again, you can modify the function to return a dataset/data table instead of list of items and you are there.

EDIT: forgot to add my StrSplit function

```
USE [MYDB_NAME_HERE]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- FUNCTIONALITY: splits a [delimeter] separated string into list of items: 1 item == 1 record
--                e.g. "that;wasn't;chicken" delimetered by ";" will turn into a recordset of 3 records
-- =============================================
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[StrSplit]    (
@strSep char(1) = ';',      --REQUIRED, the character to split the @List string on
@myList varchar(max)--REQUIRED, the list to split apart
                    )
RETURNS @sItems TABLE (txItem varchar(10))
AS
BEGIN
    IF @myList IS NULL RETURN
```

```
DECLARE @iStart int
DECLARE @iPos int

IF SUBSTRING(@myList,1,1) = @strSep
    BEGIN
        SET @iStart = 2
        INSERT INTO @sItems
        VALUES
            (NULL)
    END
ELSE
    SET @iStart = 1
WHILE 1=1
BEGIN
    SET @iPos = CHARINDEX( @strSep, @myList, @iStart )
    IF @iPos = 0 SET @iPos = LEN( @myList )+1
    IF @iPos - @iStart > 0
        INSERT INTO @sItems
        VALUES
            (SUBSTRING( @myList, @iStart, @iPos-@iStart ))
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO @sItems
        VALUES
            (NULL)
    SET @iStart = @iPos+1
    IF @iStart > len( @myList ) 
        BREAK
END
RETURN
```

END

*(using a complicated function to explode list, instead of an SP which would be much simplier because of SQL Server limitations related to cross calling -SPs vs Functions-)*